# Store instance of class A in instance of class B

Tags: python, oop

I have a question which is more regarding OOP in general rather than python specific.

Is ist possible to store instances of ClassA in instance of ClassB without a specific method, i.e. by some kind of inheritance.

Example: let's say I have one `Model class` and one `Variable class`

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = []

    def _update_vars(self,Variable):
        self.vars.append(Variable)

class Variable(Model):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Is it now possible to call `_update_vars` whenever an instance of variable is being created.

So if I do something like this:

```
mdl = Model()
varA = Variable(...)
varB = Variable(...)
```

that `mdl.vars` would now include `varA` and `varB`.

I know that I could easily do this by passing the variables as an argument to a "public" method of Model. So I am not looking for

`mdl.update_vars(varA)`

So my two questions are:

1. is this possible?
2. if yes: would this very non-standard OOP programming?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by "store" ? what do you expect to accomplish?

Comment: I mean that my instance `mdl` can access both instances of Variable via `mdl.vars`. So if I do `mdl.vars[0]` it would return the instance "varA" of class Variable.

Comment: How could `Variable` possibly know *which* instance of `Model` to update?  Unless `Model` is intended to be a singleton class, you'd have to explicitly pass a `Model` to `Variable`'s constructor.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your swift reply. As I am a self taught programmer I wasn't sure if there is some way I just didn't see.

Comment: Could you use a decorator to hook some function that returns `self` from `Variable` into `Model`?

Comment: As mentioned by @jasonharper at some point the `Variable` instance would still need to know which `Model` instance it is adhered to, so you'd eventually end up with some variation of `varA = Variable(mdl, ...)` or `mdl.varA = Variable()`.  Either way though, that's not how inheritance works in OOP, there's no point to inherit unless the child class is sharing a substantial amount of the attributes and methods in the parent class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how class inheritance is supposed to work.  You only want to inherit something if the child class is going to make use of a good amount of the attributes/methods within the parent class.  If the child class has a markedly different structure it should be a class of its own.

In either case, as mentioned by @jasonharper, at some point you would need to give direction as to which `Variable` instance belongs in which `Model` instance, so you're likely to end up with something like these:

```
varA = Variable(mdl, ...)
# or this
mdl.varA = Variable(...)
```

---

With the first way, you would maintain the method on your `Variable` class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = []

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo_instance, **kwargs):
        foo_instance.vars.append(self)

f = Foo()
b = Bar(f, hello='hey')
f.vars
# [<__main__.Bar object at 0x03F6B4B0>]
```

---

With the second way, you can append the `Variable` instances into a `list` each time it's added:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = []
    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        self.__dict__.update({name: val})
        if not name == 'vars':  # to prevent a recursive loop
            self.vars.append(val)

f = Foo()
f.vars
# []

f.a = 'bar'
f.vars
# ['bar']
```

Of course, an easier way would be to just look directly into the `__dict__` each time you want `vars`:

```
class Bar:
    @property
    def vars(self):
        # Or you can return .items() if you want both the name and the value
        return list(self.__dict__.values())

b = Bar()
b.a = 'hello'
b.vars
# ['hello']
```

Both of these will work the same even if you assigned the attributes with your own class instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples and your explanations. This helps me to understand the different approaches. Do I understand it correctly that you don't prefer Vinay's solution because it requires "inheritance" although it is not used in it's original itention?

Comment: You're welcome.  And no, Inheritance shouldn't really be used this way.  It is applicable if you have a parent class like `Car` and want a child class like `ElectricCar`, where it share a lot of the likeness of the parent class but have a few differences of its own.  More like a slight deviation.  But in this case, I'm not sure how `Variable` would be a variation of `Model` especially if you want its instances housed under `Model`.  Also, the other solution uses [class attributes](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php), which isn't instance specific.

Comment: In a word, the other solution would tack *all* `Variable` instances into *all* your `Model` instances.  Say you have `model_A` and `model_B`, and created `var_A1, var_A2, var_B1, var_B2`... you will find the same list of `[var_A1, var_A2, var_B1, var_B2, ...]` across both `modelA` and `model_B`.  Which, based on your question, is not what you need.

Comment: I just realized this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use super() for this and pass the instance to the parent

```
class Model():
    vars = []

    def __init__(self, other=None):
        if other:
            self.vars.append(other)


class Variable(Model):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        super().__init__(self)


mdl = Model()
varA = Variable(3)
varB = Variable(4)
print(mdl.vars)
```

Comment: in `varible` class OP is taking input as key value not as single variable

Comment: That does not matter, a is just a placeholder, it can be replaced by anything

Comment: The solution in this answer is not the `super()` call (you don't even need that) but the fact that you made `vars` a class variable. You probably should expand on that a bit, it might actually be what the OP was aiming for and a bit of explanation and links to docs always help.

Comment: @shmee The question is *"...is it possible to store instances of ClassA in **instance of ClassB**..."*, so no, class attribute is definitely not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @VinayBharadhwaj thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @shmee how would I achieve what Vinay is proposing without using super()?

Comment: Given the comments from @Idlehands I have accepted his answer. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: @Idlehands At the same time the OP referred to themselves as a "self taught programmer" so there is always a chance that terminology is not used accurately. Which is why I asked Vinay to explain how their approach works so that the OP have a chance to check if this really helps to meet their goal, given how class attributes work. In the end, the decision if an approach actually _is_ the answer is always with the person asking the question, not with random commenters like you or me ;)

Comment: @shmee Definitely, nobody but the OP knows exactly what they needed.  But in this case I do feel the question was rather clear that they wanted instances of class A within instances of class B, I didn't feel like there was much room of interpretation there unless the OP is fundamentally flawed in their understanding of OOP.  I myself am self taught too so I understand the struggle.  In the end though I do agree regardless if an answer is suitable for the question, more explanation and clarification is always better plus the off chances it helps other visitors of the same question.

Comment: @Idlehands The part of the question where the OP described their desired outcome is what made me wonder if this answer might actually help, despite the fact that it uses class attributes, hence my comment. However, I fully agree with your answer, especially given the OP's clarification, so I upvoted it, Have a nice day!